# Xcode 5 how to enable Jump bar

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Somehow I disabled the Jump bar

How do i get that

I searched in preferences I can't find anything

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows up when you have the Assistant Editor active.

```
View - Assistant Editor - Show Assistant Editor
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I closed Xcode and reverted my workspace file and then I got it back.